# Is "selbstbewusst" a negative word?

Tags: meaning, connotation

Sometimes I see translations of *selbstbewusst* as *confident*, *arrogant* or *selfish*. I would like to know if this word has a negative or positive denotation. If I call someone of *selbstbewusst*, is it a compliment or not?

Comment: Wenn Du jemanden selbstbewusst nennst, dann solltest Du am besten wissen, ob Du es wertend verstanden wissen willst oder beschreibend, und wenn wertend, wie.

Answer (score 26):

Generally, "selbstbewusst" has a positive connotation and I've rarely heard it used in a negative way.

It *could* be used as an euphemism for arrogant or selfish, however. Tone and context would help you decide if that's the fact.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this Answer, but 13 upvotes in three hours? Come on. Is this some kind of insider joke that I'm not getting?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: this question has found its way onto the [Stack Exchange Hot Questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions). That usually inflates the vote-count quite considerably. (I fully agree with your comment, by the way).

Comment: "Selbstbewusst" and "selfish" are completely different things. Selfish = egoistisch.

Answer (score 10):

*Selbstbewusst* is chiefly approving.

> Er präsentiert[=zeigt] sich sehr selbstbewusst.

If you want to imply that the confidence is rather negative you have to state that the confidence is exaggerated. This is possible by simply saying that the confidence is *too much*:

> Er zeigt sich zu selbstbewusst.

Alternatively you can say that the confidence conveys arrogance or similar:

> Sein selbstbewusstes Auftreten wirkt manchmal eher arrogant.

Comment: +1: "zu selbstbewusst" has a clear negative connotation. As almost all instances of "zu ___".

Comment: @Joachim: ausser wenn die Dame sagt "zu mir" :)

Answer (score 7):

*Selbstbewusst* may also refer to self-awareness, meaning the ability to get something straight in one's own mind. At an extreme extent this may lead to selfishness.

Still I hardly hear it being used for anything but *confident* in everyday language while living in Germany. The only common negative connotation was pointed out nicely by Em1.

So in conclusion I'd say that callin someone *selbstbewusst* can be regarded a compliment.

Comment: +1 for mentioning self-aware!!

Answer (score 4):

Context is everything and I'm not a native speaker, so as a result I most likely would consider the entire sentence before concluding as to whether the word's connotation is positive or negative.

EDIT: However, two native speakers have said that they have rarely heard the word with a negative connotation, so take our answers with a grain of salt; it *could* have a negative connotation, but rarely ever *does*.

Comment: then this word can have both denotations, positive and negative, depending of the context?

Comment: Depending on the sentence in which the word is used, I would believe so.

Comment: I have rarely (maybe even never) heard this word in a negative connotation.

Comment: @heinrich5991 Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @user42912 No, it never has a negative DEnotation. Denotation is the dictionary definition of a word, and I doubt you will find any dictionary that gives "arrogant" or "selfish" as part of the definition. By the way, many people -- though obviously not you -- are tripped up by the [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) "selbstbewusst" <--> "self-conscious", just something to keep in mind perhaps.

Comment: It is a **false** "false friend". See my answer and german wikipedia http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstbewusstsein Don't be fooled by the false friend hoax.

Comment: What "hoax"? If you know the meaning of the word "self-conscious" then you know that it is not congruent with the meaning of _selbstbewusst_. However, many people wrongly assume that it is.

Comment: Both "selbstbewusst" and "self-conscious" have one meaning in everyday speech, and a different meaning in psychology. And a "self-conscious" person in the everyday meaning is quite the opposite of "selbstbewusst"; a "self-conscious" person is one who is aware of all their faults and expects everyone to notice them all the time.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: It's something positive. If someone says you are "selbstbewusst" in 99% it's something positive.

Aside:
People with the property "selbstbewusst" are human who are sure about their skills and are not afraid to go some risks.

"Selbstbewusstsein": "Knowledge of your self"

Answer (score 4):

Falls das Wort *"selbstbewusst"* heutzutage dabei ist, eine negative Konnotation anzunehmen, habe ich es als Muttersprachlerin noch nicht mitbekommen.

Dafür gibt es ja schon *selbstzufrieden/arrogant/hochnäsig* oder was auch immer. Das bedeutet etwas ähnliches, aber in negativerer Weise.

Answer (score -1):

Actually the real meaning of the word is more along the lines of `self-conscious` / `self aware`, but in recent years it has mostly been used a synonym for `confident`. A tipical example hereof are low-lifes acting `over confident / cocky` and being refered to or referring to themselves as `selbstbewusst` in a positiv way. This makes the whole expression quite paradox, as overestimating one's own abilities is the exact opposite of `self-conscious` / `self-aware`. Hence, I would say most uses of the term `selbstbewusst` are negativ, even if not intended by the person using the word.

> If I call someone of selbstbewusst, is it a compliment or not?

While lower educated people do often use it as an honestly meant complement (e.g. you're not afraid of tackling this task), I would be very cautious if an intellectual superior used that word to describe you, as it may mean that you are lacking skills, but at the same time are bragging about begin the best.

To give you an answer to your question: It depends on the social (social class & education) context, but, contrary to the other answers given, it may well have a negativ touch.

A important quote from the wikipedia article on [Selbstbewusstsein](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstbewusstsein) to back up my statements (please read the whole article, it also gives examples of Kant's and Hegel's holistic interpreations of the word, which do **not only focus on the positiv** side):

*Die affirmative (positive) Konnotierung im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch des Begriffs verstellt den reinen Wortsinn: Denn ein Modus des Selbstbewusstseins in diesem Sinne wäre beispielsweise nicht nur der Stolz, sondern ebenso die Scham.*

Translation (feel free to improve):

The affirmative (positive) secondary meaning (connotation) of this term, which is used in common language, changes its pure literal sense:  E.g. a mode of the term `Selbstbewusstsein` may not only be proudness, but also shame.

**EDIT** (some current uses of the term `selbstbewusst`, resulting from the discussion):

I found a [Ph.D. thesis](http://webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/ebook/ra/2004/erassme/02_194.pdf) in the area of artificial intelligence from 2002. In chapter 3.2.6  `Selbstbewusstsein` is defined very broadly with no hint to any positiv or negativ side effects. You could summarize it, as Eugene said, as *seiner selbst bewusst*. This logically makes the term self-aware **no** "false friend" of `selbstbewusst`, as it is still used in its **literal meaning**.

Comment: Comments? Here we go: *selbstbewusst* is not used "to make fun of people". *Selbstbewusst* is not differently used in different social classes. *Selbstbewusst*, furthermore, do not have different connotation when used by different social classes. And there isn't any negative touch in common use of the word. The rare exception are given above. Can't tell about the "real meaning in former times" but etymology wasn't asked in the question. Conclusion: -1. Sorry.

Comment: We live in "these days". And we have to live and accept with what people understand in "these days". And I never lived in "other days" so I do not know any other meaning of *selbstbewusst".

Comment: "These days"™ only refers to a whole sub generation misusing the word, which does not automatically make the correct meaning invalid. `Selbstbewusst` broken down is `self-aware`  and is "wrongly" used as `confident`. Some social classes pick up expressions with less vetting, thus you have to differentiate between who is using the word.

Comment: Do you have any sources for the claim that "selbstbewußt" means "self-concious"? Because I can't find any hint of that (just places that mention them as false friends!). Also: the "other" meaning of "selbstbewußt" that I can find is "conscious of the self" in a philosophical sense ("Who am I?"), which could be translated of "self-confcious" but still isn't meant in the "negative" sense.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I answered without reading the german wiki entry first, but it covers my answer quite well - e.g. it differentiates between the "common" use and how Kant and Hegel understood it "correctly". You have to read the whole article, but here one excerpt backing up my statements: *Die affirmative (positive) Konnotierung im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch des Begriffs verstellt den reinen Wortsinn: Denn ein Modus des Selbstbewusstseins in diesem Sinne wäre beispielsweise nicht nur der Stolz, sondern ebenso die Scham.* See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstbewusstsein for more.

Comment: @FranzKafka: well, then we probably just differ in one point: I don't think that any of those two meanings (the original, philosophical one and the "newer", colloquial one) is "more correct" than the other. Like thousands of other words, "Selbstbewußtsein" has multiple meanings and none of them is "wrong" in any meaningful sense of the word. It's just that the colloquial one is more widely used (and has thus turned into the "primary" one).

Comment: Language is a very democratic thing... maybe the most democratic of all. So if everyone says "A", and mean "B" and 9 out of 10 understand "B" correctly, then A is probably "B". Luckily, in a democracy everyone is entitled to his or her own connotation. That said, you do yound very "selbstbewusst" with regard to your education and your intellect. Now, is that a compliment or an insult? I don't know... difficult to decide.

Comment: @Emanuel If democracy is the new rule for language, then German is going down the shitter. E.g. 99/100 people (on the inter-web) write `standart` instead of `standard`. Does that make it correct? I don't think so. Micro-democracy always sucks, because to many thugs make too hasty or emonatially based decisions.

Comment: @JoachimSauer _"'conscious of the self' in a philosophical sense ('Who am I?'), which could be translated as 'self-conscious'"_: In current English usage, "self-conscious" is a synonym for "awkward", "tongue-tied", "shy", "embarrassed", etc. It is not used to denote awareness of self.

Comment: Spelling is not language. Spelling is an agreed on system to capture language in writing. Agreed on by commissions and a good thing. But language was there long before spelling and despite spelling there are still dialects. So.. if language wants to change, you can try your best to prevent that change from happening but in the end, majority will prevail.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Interesting point that the English version `self-conscious` in common use spills over to the negativ side, and the German one to the positiv side :-)

Comment: @Emanuel Very true. 100% right one that one. But the perceived majority (internet crowd) may not always be a good indicatior for the general population. Best example is this whole Q&A dialog.

Comment: Can we find agreement that *"Selbstbewusstheit"* when used in the context of philosophy may have a meaning different to common sense usage? We should clearly say so in this answer.

Comment: @Takkat Not an expert on philosophy hence do not know if philosophers may use _selbstbewusst_ that way. But in ordinary usage, what you are thinking of would be expressed by _seiner selbst bewusst_.

Comment: Conceded. We would need to do a investigation or present credible sources on the use of selbstbewusst to find out.
btw: @Takkat: thanks for the deletion... I meant to write a comment and was wondering where it went :)

Comment: Found one interesting use in a Ph.D. thesis in the area of A.I.. More will follow.

Comment: Regarding the latest edit of this Answer: (1) Whatever may be said about _Selbstbewusstsein_, this Question asked about the adjective _selbstbewusst_, not the noun. (2) I don't think anyone here claimed that "self-aware" is a [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) of _selbstbewusst_, thus I am puzzled at the reference to "self-aware" -- in any case I am not commenting here on whether it is indeed such a false friend.

Comment: Ich glaube ich bin Franz Kafka ähnlicher Meinung, dass "selbstbewußt" heute vor allem als "selbsteingenommen" gebraucht wird - genau von den 90%, die auch Emanuel zu kennen scheint. Dass diese das auch noch positiv werten ändert nichts an der divergierenden Einschätzung was das Wort überhaupt bedeuten soll. Ein schüchterner, zurückhaltender und bescheidener Mensch kann sehr selbstbewusst sein - die Masse assoziiert aber mit selbstbewusst einen testosteronstrotzenden Büffel von Mann, der mit dem Kopf durch die Wand will und es wahrscheinlich auch hinbekommt.

Comment: **Please do abuse comments for extended discussions.** For further clarification use [chat] or edit posts to incorporate resolved issues. Thank you.

Comment: WTF????????????